# How to Move file using Script

Tags: shell-script, mv, mkdir

I have been asked to design a script which when executed, moves the file types given in the arguments to the respective folder(creates the folder with file type if not there).

Like suppose I give command ./M6.sh mp3 txt

This should move all mp3 files in the current working directory into a folder named "mp3" and copy all mp3 files into that and also moves all the text files from current working directory to folder named txt.

I wrote the below code, but I am facing trouble with mv command.

Please help.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to U&L.  Please post code as text, rather than images (see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51144/how-do-i-post-code-in-stackoverflow ).  Also, post details of what results/errors you get when attempted to run the problematic code.

Comment: What is the nature of the trouble that you are facing?

Comment: what does this mean? `This should move all mp3 files in the current working directory into a folder named "mp3" and copy all mp3 files into that`  .... please edit your post

Comment: In addition to the improvements in the answers below: instead of `myarray=("$@"); path="${myarray[0]}"`, do `path="$1"; shift; myarray=("$@")`.  Then you wouldn't have to loop from the 2nd element to the last - `shift` removes the 1st parameter from $@, so it never gets in to `myarray`.   Also, you don't need myarray at all, you could just loop over $@.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is needlessly complicated.  I believe that the issue is that you fail to call `mv` if the destination directory doesn't already exist. You also seem to try to move thing to a directory in the root directory.

Consider

```sh
#!/bin/sh

for suffix do
    mkdir -p -- "$suffix" || exit 1
    mv -- *."$suffix" "$suffix"
done
```

or,

```bash
#!/bin/bash

suffixes=( "$@" )

for suffix in "${suffixes[@]}"; do
    mkdir -p -- "$suffix" || exit 1
    mv -- *."$suffix" "$suffix"
done
```

(Change the `exit 1` to `continue` if you want to skip forward to the next given suffix when a directory can't be created, rather than to terminate the script).

This would loop over all filename suffixes (not really *file types* as a file type in Unix are things like "regular file", "directory", "symbolic link" etc.), would create a subdirectory in the current directory named after that suffix, and then move all files with names ending in `."$suffix"` to that directory.

The command `mkdir -p dirname` would not fail if the directory `dirname` already exists.

Example run:

```
$ tree
.
|-- file1.mp3
|-- file1.png
|-- file1.txt
|-- file2.mp3
|-- file2.png
|-- file2.txt
|-- file3.mp3
|-- file3.png
|-- file3.txt
|-- file4.mp3
|-- file4.png
|-- file4.txt
|-- file5.mp3
|-- file5.png
|-- file5.txt
`-- script.sh

0 directory, 16 files
```

```
$ ./script.sh txt mp3
```

```
$ tree
.
|-- file1.png
|-- file2.png
|-- file3.png
|-- file4.png
|-- file5.png
|-- mp3
|   |-- file1.mp3
|   |-- file2.mp3
|   |-- file3.mp3
|   |-- file4.mp3
|   `-- file5.mp3
|-- script.sh
`-- txt
    |-- file1.txt
    |-- file2.txt
    |-- file3.txt
    |-- file4.txt
    `-- file5.txt

2 directories, 16 files
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using mv commdand you are actually trying to move it to a folder from the root directory. Your command should be from the current directory.

```
mv *.${myarray[$index]} ./${myarray[$index]}/
```

Notice the `.` before directory, it tells you to look for the folder in current directory otherwise you can simply write :

```
mv *.${myarray[$index]} ${myarray[$index]}/
```

Above command will also look for the folder in the current directory.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble That was a typo. I fixed it. Thanks for pointing it out.